# Why are function argument names unimportant in c++ declarations?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, standards

Function argument names in declarations (that most likely reside in the header file) are seemingly completely ignored by the compiler. What are the *reasons* for allowing the following to compile using either declaration version 1 or 2?

---

**implementation**

```
void A::doStuff(int numElements, float* data)
{
    //stuff
}
```

---

**declaration - Version 1**

```
class A
{
public:
    void doStuff(int numElements, float* data);
}
```

---

**declaration - Version 2**

```
class A
{
public:
    void doStuff(int, float*);
}
```

Comment: It's not to do with the header, the distinction it's that it's a declaration.

Comment: Good point. Question edited. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler only needs to know what kind of arguments the method requires. It's unimportant for the compiler how you call them.

The compiler needs to know the argument types for several reasons:

- Decide which method to use if there are several methods with the same method name
- Decide whether the input parameters are valid
- Decide whether the parameters need to be casted
- Decide how to generate the CODE to call the method and handle the response

However, I suggest to use the first header version. It helps other developers (and yourself) to use the functions and know what parameters have which meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Parameter names aren't part of the function signature. Unless you use them, you don't **need** to have names even in the function implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Because the names don't affect anything the compiler does outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think about that version 1 is better is readability. They are ignored as they don't matter for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

..because when the headers are included in other modules it only needs the types to generate the correct code.  The names ae often useful and convenient, but nopt absolutely necessary.